# Angular 2 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'createMessage' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have the following Javascript file that i would like to import into my Angular 2 project without re-writing the whole thing in Typescript.

When everything is tied up correctly i get the following error...

"EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createMessage' of undefined"

Here are my corresponding files...

applicationAPI.js

```
var myApplication = myApplication || {};

(function(myApplication) {

myApplication.Message = function() {
    this.m_messageContents = "New Message";
};

myApplication.Message.prototype.getApplicationMessageContents = function() {
    return this.m_messageContents;
};

myApplication.SystemFactory = (function(){
    var factory =        
    {
        createMessage: function() {
            return new myApplication.Message();
        }
    };
    return factory;
}());

}(myApplication));
```

applicationAPI.d.ts

```
declare module "myApplicationAPI" {

export interface Message {
    getApplicationMessageContents(): string;
}

export class SystemFactory {
    static createMessage(): Message;
}

}
```

strangely I can get this working when applicationAPI.js looks like the following with the same applicationAPI.d.ts file.

applicationAPI.js

```
(function() {

this.Message = function() {
    this.m_messageContents = "New Message";
};

this.Message.prototype.getApplicationMessageContents = function() {
    return this.m_messageContents;
};

this.SystemFactory = (function(){
    var factory =        
    {
        createMessage: function() {
            return new this.Message();
        }
    };
    return factory;
}());}());
```

Any thoughts on what else needs to be added for this scenario to work? It is not obvious to me...

This is where the call is coming from...

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as myApp from "myApplicationAPI";
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
title: string;

constructor() {}
ngOnInit() {
this.title = myApp.SystemFactory.createMessage().getApplicationMessageContents();
}
}
```

Comment: On what line are you getting the error? It doesn't look like you actually call `SystemFactory.createMessage()` anywhere

Comment: The call is coming from my "home.component.ts" file, i have added it. Everything works fine with the later use case but once i introduce the "myApplication" object in the js it breaks.

Comment: My hunch is that the issue is in the .d.ts file but am not sure of the solution.

Comment: `.d.ts` files should have no impact on how your app actually runs. There's no operational code in them.

Comment: so your solution is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not exporting anything out of applicationAPI.js so you can't import anything from it. When you `import * as myApp from "myApplicationAPI";` you're not getting what you think you're getting.

Your first instinct might be to export `myApplication` but you should be exporting classes and interfaces, not instances. Let Angular's Dependency Injector handle instances.

I'd recommend a pattern more like this:

applicationAPI.ts

```
import Injectable from '@angular/core';
// either define Message in this file or import it as well
// if you define it here, export it as well

@Injectable
export class Api {
  static createMessage(): Message {
    return new Message();
  }
}
```

home.component.ts

```
import Api from 'applicationAPI';
...
  constructor (private api: Api) {...}
```

And assuming your bootstrap call looks something like `bootstrap(HomeComponent)` it should be changed to be

```
import Api from 'applicationAPI';
...
bootstrap(HomeComponent, [Api]);
```

This will insure that every time `Api` is injected, it's the same instance although that may not matter to you if all the methods on the class are static.

`.d.ts` files are used as reference by the typescript compiler saying something along the lines of "trust me, there's something that looks and acts like this" such as when you want your typescript to interface with a JS library. That library still has to be defined somewhere else outside of the `.d.ts` file. **Nothing you put in a `.d.ts` file will execute or even be seen by the browser.** If `Message` is only defined in a `.d.ts` file then you can't use `new Message` because at the end of the day when the javascript is running in the browser there won't be any definition for what a `Message` is.

Comment: I understand this approach, however, my goal here was to not re-write any of the applicationAPI.js into applicationAPI.ts but to use it as is from my ts files... is there no way from my "home.component.ts" to do this? It seems odd to me that you can't just add the js file as a "reference\import" and code away. The problem here is that the scoping of "myApplication" in applicationAPI.js is lost, right? Just trying to understand the true behavior of this process and there isn't a lot of quality examples from what i've been able to find.

Comment: You might be able to write a .d.ts describing all of applicationAPI.js's behavior and properties and then add one line to the bottom of applicationAPI.js: `window.myApp = myApplication;`. The .d.ts would also need to state that this interface exists on the Window object. Then you wouldn't have to import anything to have access to `window.myApp` in your ts. This is how jQuery can be used along side typescript (honestly this has nothing to do with Angular with this approach).

Comment: Adding the following to my d.ts file... 
export interface window {
        myApplication: any;
 }
yields the following build error in "home.component.ts"
"Property 'myApplication' does not exist on type 'Window'." when i add the following line...
"if (typeof window.myApplication === "undefined"){}"

Comment: Try `export interface Window {...}`. Note that Window is capitalized.

Comment: neither combination works, same error. Is it something to do with the way i am importing the module?

Comment: I managed to get it working, I had initially placed the Window interface inside the module declaration. I realize now that this is incorrect, after moving it out it all works as expected. Thanks, Corey.